# Derivative in Sobolev space extended by zero

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, sobolev-spaces, hilbert-spaces, derivations

Let $u(x) \in H^1_0$ is a complex function in sobolev space extension by zero.
How to find $J'(u)$ for
$$
J(u)= \int\limits_0^l |u(x)|^2\operatorname{d\!}x\;??
$$
In $L_2$ it's easy:
$$
J'(u) = \left(\int\limits_0^l|u(x)|^2 \operatorname{d\!}x\right)'=\big(\|u(x)\|^2\big)'= 2 u(x),
$$
but it does not work with $H^1_0$, where
$$
\|u(x)\|^2_{H^1_0} = \int\limits_0^l |u'(x)|^2  \operatorname{d\!}x
$$

Comment: Your assertion that $J'(u)=2u(x)$ is wrong and actually makes no sense, for several reasons, including the following: (i) the $x$ there is undefined; (ii) $J'(u)$ is a linear functional, while $u(x)$ is a number (if $x$ is a point between $0$ and $l$); (iii) we can identify $J'(u)$, in a certain manner, with $2u$ only if $u$ is real valued. See the answer below for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We shall assume that $l\in(0,\infty)$, so that for any $h\in H_0^1$ we have
$$\int_0^l|h|^2=\int_0^l dx\,\Big|\int_0^x h'\Big|^2 
\le\int_0^l dx\,\Big(\int_0^l|h'|\Big)^2 \\ 
\le\int_0^l dx\,l\,\int_0^l|h'|^2=l^2\|h\|^2_{H_0^1}. \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Next, for any $u$ and $h$ in $H_0^1$, in view of \eqref{1},
$$J(u+h)-J(u)-2\int_0^l\Re(\bar uh)=\int_0^l|h|^2=o(\|h\|_{H_0^1})$$
as $\|h\|_{H_0^1}\to0$. So, the ([Fréchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition)) derivative $J'(u)$ of $J$ at $u\in H_0^1$ is the linear functional on $H_0^1$ given by the formula
$$J'(u)(h)=2\int_0^l\Re(\bar uh)$$
for $h\in H_0^1$.

Comment: thank you very much! I may not have fully understood, but why is there a dependence on h in the Frechet derivative in the last equation?

Comment: @anon.for : The Fréchet derivative $J'(u)$ of $J$ at $u$ is a linear functional on $H_0^1$, and this linear functional depends only on $u$. However, the **value** $J'(u)(h)$ of the linear functional $J'(u)$ at $h\in H_0^1$ depends, of course, on $h$.